# Sixth Cross Validated Journal Club

Tags: discussion, journal-club

Time to continue the CVJC series in 2012!

To remind for those who are new to the idea:

- CVJC is a meeting on [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18/ten-fold) where we discuss some paper and its theoretical/practical surroundings.
- It usually takes place on Friday about 18:00UTC.
- The paper must be OpenAccess or a (p)reprint suggested previously on a meta thread like this one and selected in voting.
- We will try to invite the author(s).

So, please suggest papers (each in one answer)! The deadline for suggestions is <strike>traditionally a week ahead, so 23:59UTC 13.1.2012</strike> 23:59UTC 20.1.2012 (postponed due to a lack of paper proposals).

EDIT: Current approximation of the spacetime coordinates is 24.2.2012 (Friday) 16:00UTC; you can (please do) register [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/18/ten-fold?tab=schedule).

EDIT: <strike>The author confirmed his presence at the event.</strike>

FINAL EDIT: This time it was not too fruitful; yet here you can find the [transcript](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18/conversation/cross-validated-journal-club-6).

Comment: Make sure y'all make a [community promotion ad](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1030/community-promotion-ads-1h-2012/1031#1031) for this! :D It would help get the word out about this recurring chat event. [DIY](http://diy.stackexchange.com) has an ad like this up on their site.

Comment: @Aarthi Good idea; I still forget that there are people not using AdBlock (-;

Comment: fyi - http://akademeia.ca is a relatively new open-source journal. They've only had 2 issues so far, but might be something to keep an eye on for papers in the future.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Having been brought up as a frequentist, I'm now reading up on Bayesian methods (greatly enjoying increasing the size of my statistical toolbox!). While doing a literature search I recently stumbled upon the following paper, which I think could be interesting to discuss.

Fraser, D.A.S. (2011), Is Bayes Posterior just Quick and Dirty Confidence?, *Statistical Science*, Vol. 26, No. 3, 299-316, [arXiv:1112.5582v1 [stat.ME]](http://arxiv.org/abs/1112.5582)

Discussions and rejoinders can be found on [projecteuclid](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ss/1320066918) for those who have access. For those that don't, below are some of the discussion and rejoinder papers collected from the authors' websites. Some of them may not be official final versions.

[Discussion](http://basepub.dauphine.fr/xmlui/bitstream/handle/123456789/6735/STS1106-004R0A0.pdf) by Christian P. Robert (our own [Xi'an](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/7224/xian)).

[Discussion](http://www.stat.rutgers.edu/home/mxie/RCPapers/DiscussionsOnDrFraserStatSciPaperNew2.pdf) by K. Singh and M. Xie.

[Discussion](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ss/1320066921) by L. Wasserman. (Not open access.)

[Discussion](http://arxiv.org/abs/1201.0588) by T. Zhang.

[Rejoinder](http://arxiv.org/abs/1201.0611) by D. A. S. Fraser.

Comment: For those that have access, there are also several "discussion" papers and a rejoinder. Links to them can be found on [projecteuclid](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ss/1320066918). I'm not sure if there is an open-access link to them.

Comment: I think I saw them on arXiv, in connection with this paper. Will have a look again as soo  as I have the time.

Comment: I chased down all of them except for Larry Wasserman's. A couple of them looked like they might not be the final official version.

Comment: I don't know whether Bayes posterior is dirty, but what I know for sure is that it's not quick! :-)

Comment: BTW, I had a look at the paper and don't really understand what this means. Are there any practical consequences for us ecologists using WinBUGS? I'll be curious for conclusions of your debate!!

Comment: I am probably going to be late at this starts at 5am Sat for me, but I will show up when I wake up. :)